# Do I not have any alleles from my mom's mom & my dad's dad?

Tags: human-biology, genetics, gene-synthesis

So, I have an XX, & I got an X from my mom, & an X from my dad. My dad would have gotten his only X from his mother, & my mother could have gotten the X I got from her father or mother. That would mean I did not get either X gene from either my mom's mom or dad, or my dad's dad - does that mean that I have "less" of their genetics in me? Say I got my mom's dad's X, would that mean I have less of my mom's mom's genetic traits?

Answer (score 20):

Speaking of your DNA in general, you have alleles from all four of your grandparents.  The 22 pairs of autosomes (non-sex chromosomes) can receive DNA from all four with random mixing.  On a few chromosome pairs you may be missing alleles from one of your grandparents due to the randomness, but on average you will have about a quarter of your autosomes from each of them.

The X (and Y, for males) chromosomes are special, though.  The X you inherit from your mother will have alleles from both your maternal grandparents.  The X that you, as a female, get from your father has no alleles from his father, so that grandfather's X alleles are always missing from your genome.

Because of the random mixing, you will have slightly varying amounts of DNA from each of your grandparents: it won't be exactly 25% for each of them.  Because of the special X inheritance, your paternal grandfather will on average contribute slightly less than the other three grandparents.  (Because of another quirk, mitochondrial inheritance, your maternal grandmother will contribute on average a very small amount more than the other three grandparents.)

Comment: Regarding your second paragraph, you should consider recombination between the pseudoautosomal regions of the X and Y chromosome.

Comment: Nice summary. Sex chromosome inheritance is interesting, for instance that paternal grandmothers are on average more closely related to their granddaughters than their grandsons: [Fox et al. 2009. *Grandma plays favourites: X-chromosome relatedness and sex-specific childhood mortality*. Proc. Roy. Soc. B](http://rspb.royalsocietypublishing.org/content/early/2009/10/27/rspb.2009.1660.full)